# NumberFormatException when typecasting from String Array to Double

Tags: android, numberformatexception

i am trying to convert a string to a double. I was able to do it in many situations but this time, it is giving me a NumberFormatException. Here is the code...

```
//strExpression = 2^3 (My Input in the editText)

strExpression = edtxtExpression.getText().toString();

try
{
   System.out.println("Inside Power case");
   //expSplit is a String[]
   expSplit = strExpression.split("^");
   double first = Double.parseDouble(expSplit[0]);
   System.out.println("First Number "+first);
   double second = Double.parseDouble(expSplit[1]);
   System.out.println("Second Number "+second);

   double result = Math.pow(first, second);
   System.out.println("Result "+result);
   edtxtExpression.setText(first+" ^ "+second+" = "+result);

}
catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
    Toast.makeText(this, e.getClass().toString(), 100).show();

}
```

Exception:::

```
01-01 03:07:45.169: I/System.out(11287): Inside Power case
01-01 03:07:45.179: I/System.out(11287): class java.lang.NumberFormatException
```

I get the "Inside Power" output but the other print statements doesn't get executed. where am i going wrong?

Comment: catch a NumberFormatException and print out the message associated with that?

Comment: No. I just wanted to know, what the exception was. So, I had the toast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^` is a reserved character in RegEx, try `\\^`.

```
expSplit = strExpression.split("\\^");
```